# Configurar atajo de terminal dentro de visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, vscode, terminal

Tengo un problema y es que cada vez que apretó la tecla "Supr" se me abre la terminal dentro del studio visual code. Esto me resulta muy engorroso a la hora de programar, ya que cada vez que quiero borrar una palabra a partir de el siguiente carácter a partir de la posición actual del cursor se me abre la terminal.  Alguno sabe como configurar los atajos para abrir la terminal para cambiar ese atajo o para resetear a valores determinados?

Saludos.

Comment: Entra en administrar (abajo a la izquierda - la rueda) y abre los métodos abreviados de teclado. Luego revisa la sección a ver si algo cambiaste ahí. Además, comenzó a fallar por una extensión o que ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los métodos abreviados del teclado (Ctrl+K Ctrl+S) busca el método "Delete".
Verás que tienes activado "workbench.action.terminal.killInstance".
Solo tienes que editar el método que quieras usar para abrirlo. Por defecto trae "Delete".

Solo se queda activado si abres previamente el terminal. Es un posible error de la última actualización, pues antes no ocurría.

Suerte